# Get the position of scrollbars(not the position item) in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, position, scrollbar

I am implementing a timeline UI, which is basically a `ListView`. The tricky part is when the user scrolls the `ListView`, it will display a text box(shows the time slot, say 9:00 am ) next to the scrollbar. It is on the left side, adjacent and will move with the scrollbar.

I am using the `OnScrollListener` to detect the scroll event. But I don't know how to get  the exact position of the scroll bar (top, mid point, bottom), so that I can put the text box at the right place. There are many posts about getting the position of the top item but seems not for the scrollbar itself.

Any thoughts?

BTW, sorry for not attaching a screenshot of the UI. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do that since I am a new user.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how to get the exact position of the scroll bar (top,
>   mid point, bottom), so that I can put the text box at the right place

You probably want something like the `Path` application. [This tutorial](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=556) it what you're looking for(probably, if you didn't see it yet).

Basically, the `ListView` has some methods regarding the scrollbars position(also size) that are used but those methods are not available from outside as they are declared as `protected`, so you need to extend the `ListView` class. Those methods are `ListView.computeVerticalScrollExtent()`, `ListView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()` and `ListView.computeVerticalScrollRange()`.

Using those methods you should be able to figure where the scrollbars are placed at a particular moment in your listener.

Comment: Luksprog, thanks for your answer, it's really helpful. It turned out I have a misunderstanding about the UI.(I was given the design by someone else) It should works like the Android People app. It allows fast scroll when the user touch/move the scroll bar instead of scroll the list.

Comment: @RenjiYu I've installed that app and browsed it but I don't even see the scrollbars let alone the fast scroll. So what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

**getListView().getLastVisiblePosition()**

```
listview.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
    }
});
```

**View.getScrollY()**

[getScrollY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY%28%29): 
Return the scrolled top position of this view. This is the top edge of the displayed part of your view. You do not need to draw any pixels above it, since those are outside of the frame of your view on screen.

Returns
The top edge of the displayed part of your view, in pixels.

Also refer : http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/how-to-save-the-position-of-a-scrollview-when-the-orientation-changes-in-android/